# Get mysql database from raw files

Tags: linux, mysql, innodb

My root access linux server has crashed and I cannot SSH into it or interact with it. I can, however tell the online console to do a network boot to a "rescue system" which allows me to access the files on the server.

This means I can only get the raw folder of my database and I can't perform an SQL dump.

It doesn't work if I just copy the folder of my database, because on my new working server it says some tables are not available. Apparently it is because of InnoDB and that I should copy the ibdata1, ib_logfile0 and ib_logifle1 files as well.

Can I just overwrite the ib* files on my news server with the ib* files of the old server? Is there any way I can transfer this database just by copying files?

Answer (score 1):

If you copy the `ib*` files and all the subdirectories in `/var/lib/mysql` (or whatever you MySQL data directory was) along with the `my.cnf` from `/etc` to the new server, it should start up as if nothing had happened. There is no way to transfer InnoDB tables or databases other than that. Even with the [innodb_file_per_table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-multiple-tablespaces.html) option, InnoDB still stores metadata in the central database file, so you cannot recover without it.

Comment: My DB's name is "istyla". I've copied the istyla folder to the new server and it shows the db exists. If I copy the ibdata1, ib_logfile0 and ib_logfile1 to the news server, will it work. Should I overwrite the ib* files on the new server? (I don't have any other DB's on the new server.)

Comment: Yes, you must replace the ib* files. The content in the folder is just descriptive, and does not constitute the database contents.

Comment: The one table, "user" does not have an MYD or MYI file. Looks like my server has been hacked? :( Lost about 5000 user's data. I still have the other 41000, though. Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: Make sure that your ib_logfile? files have the same size. If you had set their size to a different value in my.cnf, it won't replay the transaction log.